# Problems parsing this sentence (ような before comma)

Tags: grammar, translation

I was reading the examples from the book 日本語文型辞典 and I came across this example sentence which I have absolutely no idea of how to parse it:

その子は、人と目が合うたびにやさしく笑いかけるような、そんな、人を疑うということを知らないような子だったと言う。

Is the first ような (笑いかける**ような**) modifying 子, as well as the second? And what is this そんな doing between commas?

Thanks!

Comment: `そんな` is a contraction of `そのような`, so I think it's just repetitively summing up the whole clause (`人と...笑いかけるような`) before it.

Comment: what happened to snailboat's answer?

Comment: @RodrigoPará: He deleted it.

Comment: why, exactly? It was a good answer.

Comment: I thought it didn't fully answer the question (because it didn't really explain そんな), and I thought people would be more likely to answer if it said 0 answers.  Maybe I can undelete it now, though :-) (P.S., I'm not a *he*!)

Comment: @istrasci Do you have a source for that?  I checked a bunch of dictionaries but none of them listed its etymology.  But they did note the form そんなな, and *そのようなな is presumably ungrammatical, so I suppose that it might be _historically_ a contraction, but not _synchronically_...

Comment: @snailboat:  It's one of those things that I was taught somewhere along the line.  I found a few references [here](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%81%9D%E3%82%93%E3%81%AA&dtype=3&dname=2na&stype=0&pagenum=1&index=02494500) and [here](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%9D%E3%82%93%E3%81%AA), but they don't show any etymological derivation, just association.  I've never heard そんな*な*, but definitely そんな*の*, although both of those seem ungrammatical to me (as you mentioned).

Comment: @istrasci I've never heard そんなな either.  It looks goofy to me, but dictionaries claim it's used in certain constructions.  For example, [大辞泉](http://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%9D%E3%82%93%E3%81%AA) says 『連体形に「そんな」「そんなな」の二形がある。連体形として一般には「そんな」の形が用いられるが、接続助詞「ので」「のに」などに続くときは「そんなな」の形が用いられる。「状況がそんななのに、よく無事でいられたものだ」』。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks to me like two parallel phrases have been coordinated:

> Relative clause A = `人と目が合うたびにやさしく笑いかけるような`
>   Relative clause B = `そんな、人を疑うということを知らないような`

Both relative clauses end with ようだ, conjugated to ような because they're attributive modifiers.  (An attributive modifier is one that comes before the word it modifies.)  In other words, they're being put together like a pair of adjectives.  I think you can parse it like this:

> その子は、（　Aな　Bな　）子だったと言う。

Where both Aな and Bな modify 子.

Comment: (1) I don't think そんな is modifying 人, but I'm not sure whether to say it's modifying 子. It probably is, but it's linked very closely to "relative clause B", maybe more than it is to the actual final noun "子". It's like the speaker uses そんな (and then pauses for a bit indicated by the comma) to describe that he's trying to find the best words to use for relative clause B.

Comment: (2) `a comma can come between a modifier and its head` ... can it? >_< Do you have any other examples? I am aware of plenty of "unintuitive" comma placement in Japanese but I can't remember such an example. Ordinarily a comma indicates that the immediately following noun is **not** the head but another modifier. (Assuming I understand the term "head" correctly ... here as referring to 子.) ------- (Other than that pick about そんな, I agree with your thoughts on the structure of the sentence.)

Comment: @Hyperworm You know, I could've sworn I had lots of examples, but when I looked through my notes (or at the one example I remembered on the site, [here](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12896/question-about-particle-%E3%81%AB/12897#12897)) I only found examples where the head noun came *later*.  So I think you're right and I was just confused.  Thanks for pointing that out!  I removed that part of the answer, so I should probably try to elaborate a little about what そんな does, but now I'm not feeling sure enough to do so :-(

Comment: Lol ok I'm still waiting for the explanation about the そんな =(

Comment: Okay, I undeleted this answer because you got an explanation about そんな from @ssb's answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is almost certainly meant to be a representation of spoken Japanese. The person is speaking and describing this kind of person. First the speaker offers "笑いかけるような," but deciding that isn't enough, simply interjects a そんな to be kind of like, "you know", in English. So it's like, you know, that kind of pattern where like.. you're describing something but, like, in the middle it's punctuated with these.. you know.. verbal cues that indicate thought about how to expound upon the subject.

笑いかけるような is modifying 子. So is 人を疑うということを知らないような, obviously. The そんな I guess is technically also modifying 子; essentially the three are aiming to be the same thing, both in meaning and therefore in grammatical role. What kind of 子? そんな子. そんな子ってどんな子？人を疑うということを知らないような子。笑いかけるような子。

そうなんだ。

Comment: I figured it was a representation of spoken Japanese, I just wanted to make sure if it also had another interpretation. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: No problem. No intention of sounding condescending or anything, though! I generally add excess explanations for those who might be reading the question but aren't aware of these things.